# What would be the best index for this kind of query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

So this is my table:

```
create table page_relation (
     relationid int primary key,
     userid int,
     pageid int,
     registryid int 
);
```

Let's imagine I wanna get the count of all the registries of a every page of a user alot of times.
Here is the query I am going to be running alot:

```
select count(*) as register_count
from page_relation
where userid = 10 
group by pageid;
```

I need help figuring out what is the best index to speed this quind of query.

So far I tried using a composite index over `(userid, pageid)` hoping that MySQL would use the index for group-by, but unfortunally when I use EXPLAIN the extra information does not hold any "Using index for group-by" information, only says I am using index and I am using where. Does that mean my index is not getting used for sorting?

Theoretically wouldn't this index work if it was clustered? I was thinking a B-Tree, clustered and sparse index would do the job really nicely... To be honest I was expecting it would even be a covering index, but I can't really tell if it is or not.

Here is my explain statement:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows,  Extra
  1, SIMPLE, page_relation, ref, idx_count, idx_count, 4, const, 60, Using where; Using index
```

What would be the optimal index to use to perform this query only?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Quite Interesting, I too faced it somewhere, waiting for Answers from core DBAs !  BTW, a table can only have 1 clustered index, and your tables clustered index is occupied with the primary key. you may also TRY FORCE index !

Comment: What if I remove the primary key index? Which I did.

Comment: The strength of an index depends on its cardinality. A PK has a cardinality of 1. You can't do better than that!

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, Could you please elaborate this in details, or any article ? I got your point but require some detailed info to clarify ! what exactly you meant with < "if there is a gap" >, ?

Comment: @Hytool checkout this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: This index `(userid, pageid)` is a covering index,as to your explain there is no Using index for group-by. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I get this explain, seems worse :s

1, SIMPLE, page_relation, index, , idx_page_relation_userid_pageid, 8, , 963, Using where; Using index

Comment: @PatriqDesigns you are correct eventually your index `(userid, pageid)` should be good enough since the userid is used in the where condition and pageid is used in group by ignore my comment I will delete that.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement can be met by using any of the below mentioned two approaches:

1. composite index over (userid, pageid)

Query:

```
select  userid,pageid,count(*) as register_count
from page_relation
where userid = 10 
group by userid,pageid;
```

2. Two indexes - one on userid and other one on pageid

Query : The query will remain same as it is mentioned in the question.

Note: For composite keys, MySQL uses index in the order of declaration. For example, the composite key (userid, pageid) must use field `userid` for filtering or grouping otherwise index will be ignored.

1st approach has benefit that it has to refer only one index. Less number indexes has better writing efficiency. Keeping space and time complexity in mind, I would suggest you to go for `1st approach` for `BTREE` indexing.

Assumption: `pageid` field is not unique.

Note: If index is not being used in any version of MySQL, keep `group by` fields in `select clause` as well.

Comment: Here is the explain in the first approach:
Seems the same as my first explain.. Is it the optimal one then?
1, SIMPLE, page_relation, ref, idx_count, idx_count, 4, const, 60, Using where; Using index.       

Here is the explain in the second approach:
1, SIMPLE, page_relation, ref, idx_page_relation_userid, idx_page_relation_userid, 4, const, 60, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

The second approach seems to be using filesort, isnt that bad?

Comment: @PatriqDesigns: I have updated the answer considering efficiency. Your point is valid. 1st approach has pre-cooked ordered index. 2nd approach uses run time sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(userid, pageid)
```

is the only rational index to add.

`EXPLAIN` is pretty lame when it comes to indicating whether the index (`pageid` in this case) is used or ignored.  You can try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to see if that clarifies the question.

```
INDEX(userid), INDEX(pageid)
```

is less useful.  It would use one or the other, but not both.  It would probably use (userid), but that is essentially no better, probably worse, than the composite index.

The query, itself, is puzzling.  Do you get multiple rows?  If not, get rid of the `GROUP BY`.  If so, shouldn't you add `pageid` to the `SELECT` list?

Much of this, I cover in my [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Another puzzle... This is a 'relation' table; do you mean a "many-to-many" mapping between userids and pageids?  Or something else.  In a many:many table, usually you want to go both directions, thereby necessitating indexes going both ways.  Also a surrogate `id` is useless, because `PRIMARY KEY (userid, pageid)` is warranted.  (See my cookbook.)

My upgrading this to the `PRIMARY KEY`, you make things more efficient.

I'm getting too deep in "what ifs"; address some of my questions; then I will ramble further.